# Can you make money in the stock market buying and selling the same stock?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, penny-stocks

Can you make money in the stock market buying and selling the same stock, but not all your shares; just buying at the lowest price and sell it at a higher price like the examples of recent trades:

[image]

I am new to the market and want to see if anyone uses this technique.

Comment: What alternative way of making money do you have in mind? It’s not like you can buy one stock and then sell a different one — if you buy a stock, it can only ever be with the intention of eventually selling it.

Comment: @Mke Scott  than the buy and hold let grow with dividends natural growth of a strong  company.

Comment: The stock will still be sold eventually. Even if you keep it until you die, whoever inherits it will either sell it or leave it to someone else, and in the end it will be sold.

Comment: Just curious: What is the tool/service/platform shown in the picture? Is it an Excel spreadsheet you made?

Comment: @Flux Yes, it is an Excel spreadsheet that I created for this particle trading technique.  Excel has a feature that lets you get updates in the Data tab. Try it you will like it. :)

Comment: Obviously you could make money if you bought at the lowest and sold at the highest price. Just like you could make money in the lottery had you ticked the correct numbers. There is one Problem though, you only ever know these numbers afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course.  If you sell when you've made more than your brokerage (buy & sell) you win, and of course you can't (generally) sell that which you haven't bought first.  Timing the market is literally how speculation works.  But consider that you need to ask yourself

a) So when should I sell? (obviously when it's lower than you bought)

b) Is there any more money on the table (will it go up or down from here)

c) Will it go up or down after you sell some? (should I buy more soon, leave it to go down more, or just sell the lot)

So basically you need to guess the market or do tons of research that might back up your hunch on timing.

If anyone knew the market in the future this would be a lot easier! Of course nobody does know so it's going to involve an element of risk and your reward will be the inverse of that in an efficient market.

I would say though, focusing on a small number of stocks *may* increase your likelihood of your research working for you as you become sensitive to things that matter to a specific stock, but you won't be alone in that.  Now having said that, you may get great at watching and working a 5% swing in a particular stock but missing the opportunity of a 10% growth elsewhere.

If you're a beginner, you're as likely to lose money rather than make it so I'd go with a long term buy & hold on an ETF where the fund is something you believe in.  But that's not an answer to your question.

Comment: @Bob Baeker Yes, I know it is a very unique period one of the main reasons I got in now. You are absolutely right that immediate success can be the worse thing for a beginner hence that is the reason for my question. Just looking to see what and if the some seasoned professionals tried this in past and what was the outcome in the past.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116840/discussion-on-answer-by-loztinspace-can-you-make-money-in-the-stock-market-buyin).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make money from buying and selling the same stock.

If it drops after you sell some/all of your shares, you can buy them back.

If it rises after you buy some/all of your shares, you can sell them again.

Where this becomes problematic is if:

- Price collapses and stays down so you either become a buy and holder waiting for recovery or you average down.
- Price zooms up after selling some shares and you'll either have to  buy more at the much higher price than you sold the last batch of shares, become a holder or sell all of your shares and move on to another stock.

I've traded some stocks for months like this.  I once wrote short puts on a gold stock at adjacent strike prices for over a year with no losses.  But sooner or later the party comes to an end. This strategy works only for as long as the stock cooperates.

Comment: In particular, this may not work as well as simply buying and holding a good stock, especially when you remember that there's a fee for every transaction. Or, better, buying and holding a diversified mix of stocks, or simply buying and holding a low-fee index funds.

Comment: There's a fee for every transaction? There's zero commission trading now.  If you're referring to the SEC fee of one penny per $400 for selling a stock, surely you jest?  That's inconsequential.  I have found that those who can't make money from buying and selling stocks are the ones who tell you that it can't be done.

Comment: It can be done. Whether you can sustain better than market rate of return is questionable, as is whether that is a reasonable goal at all.  FWIW, Quicken claims my lifetime APR in the market is currently 8.68% not including reinvested dividends, though the downturn reduced it to 6% if I only consider the past five years, with near-zero effort (throw money in index funds and mostly ignore them). More than good enough for me.

Comment: Zero commission trading under what conditions? They need to pay for the service somehow... "If you aren't the customer, you're the product."

Comment: Even before commissions were eliminated, they weren't the driving force behind brokerage profits.  Fidelity, Schwab, TD, Vanguard, etc. make billions of dollars per year from investors. They make money from a variety of services, which vary from broker to broker. The largest source of revenue is generally net interest income which is earned by investing customer deposits.